# Javascript run() function

Tags: javascript

```
var test = function(msg) {
  alert(msg)
};

(new test("hi")).run();
(new test("hello")).run();
```

When I run above javascript code, I am able to get alert "hi". But alert "hello" is not coming up.

1. Anybody can explain what is above, I am completely new to this. Only I know is that "test" is a function
2. What is run() method does?, because when I removed run in the above code, I am able to see both alerts, pls help...

   ```
   var test = function(msg) {
     alert(msg)
   };

   (new test("hi"));
   (new test("hello"));
   ```

Comment: Just try "test('some message');"

Comment: Even that works.... Then what is "run" and "new" does?. Any ideas?

Comment: there is no `run`, check your console, you have errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple, there is no `run` function, when your code runs `(new test("hi")).run()` it runs the `(new test("hi"))` part first, and then errors on the `run` so the second line is never executed.

If you want to call a function, call it:

```
test("hi");
```

Don't run functions (that are not constructors) as constructors. Here is [what `new` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript).

Comment: Or rather, "only run functions intended to be constructors as constructors." :)

Comment: And this explains why it doesn't go on to run the next line :)

Answer (score 4):

"run" is not a defined function.
Even if you replace "run" by "xyz"|| "abc" or any other random function name which is not defined, the code above will work in the same way.

```
var test = function(msg) {
  alert(msg)
};

/** test("hi") getting called, then xyz() throws a javascript error **/ 
(new test("hi")).xyz();

/** No Execution as there was an error on previous line **/ 
(new test("hello")).xyz();
```

Its's just that initially the "test" function is called once and when it encounters a .run() which is not defined, it throws an error and execution stops.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a find & Replace routine to read the cookie and then replace it with ''?

I have not been able to delete all path cookies using all of the tips above and am still playing with it, but I did make a bookmarklet to extract all the cookies and put them in an iframe so that you can copy&paste them.

```js
javascript: var c=document.cookie;if (c==''){alert('This site didn\'t give you any cookies at all.\nNot a single one!');}else{w=window.open('','Links','scrollbars,resizable,width=400,height=600');w.document.write(c);    }
```